# Does the dogecoin daemon support ZeroMQ feature like the bitcoin deamon?

Tags: dogecoin, zeromq

I am using Dogecoin v1.10.0 and I am wondering if the daemon, `dogecoind`, supports publishing transactions and blocks via ZeroMQ like `bitcoind` does? My `dogecoin.conf` looks like the following.

```
rpcpassword=test
rpcbind=10.211.55.111
rpcallowip=10.211.55.1/24
rpcallowip=10.211.55.111/24
zmqpubhashtx=tcp://10.211.55.111:38323
zmqpubhashblock=tcp://10.211.55.111:38323
zmqpubrawblock=tcp://10.211.55.111:38323
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://10.211.55.111:38323
txindex=1
```

I start `dogecoind` like the following `/usr/local/bin/dogecoind -datadir=/etc/data/dogecoin/data -daemon`

However, when I see which ports are listening `netstat -peanut | grep dogecoind` I only see the following.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22556               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          34038      8425/dogecoind      
tcp        0      0 10.211.55.111:22555         0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          34036      8425/dogecoind  
tcp        0      0 :::22556                    :::*                        LISTEN      0          34037      8425/dogecoind
```

As I understand port `22555` is the default RPC port, and `22556` is the port connected to by remote peers for transaction/block propagation.